# How to pass markdown to handlebars partial?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, markdown

I can call a handlebars partial with parameters, e.g. the following way:

```
{{> collapsible content="test"}}
```

Now, I'd like to pass more content than a single term, e.g. entire paragraphs, code or markdown containing line breaks. Example:

````
{{> collapsible content="
```javascript
    // test code
    alert("Hello World");
```
"}}
````

This will cause an error:

[image: Error]

What's necessary to make this work?

Comment: Create a register helper method, hope it works

Comment: Could you share a code example please?

Comment: That sort of content should in the form of data passed to your template method, not hard-coded into the template source.

Comment: I don't understand what you meeat 76484

Comment: I mean that it would be data that would be accessed in the template like, `{{> collapsible content=content}}`.